# Unable to enable ssl for spark rest api

Tags: rest, apache-spark

I used to submit spark jobs using spark rest API. I enable this configuration by adding `spark.master.rest.enabled true` inside `spark-defaults.conf` file.

Now I want to make the spark rest api url as https. But I don't see any configuration available to enable SSL for Rest API.
Can someone please help me to find a way to make the Rest API https?

I need the Spark REST API to run as https